# How do Bash local file descriptors work?

Tags: bash, file-io, file-descriptor

I have looked but can't find any Bash guide that describes the details for how the following file descriptor syntax works:

```
while read line <&3; do
    echo $line
done 3<file.txt
```

Is this a special construction for while loops that allows Bash to look after the `done` for the file descriptor source? Is it some kind of shorthand for making an exec call?

Comment: There's nothing special about looking for the redirection after the `done`. You need to realize that the entire `while ... done` construct is a single shell command (a very complex command, with potentially lots of other commands contained within it) but still it's just a command... and you can put redirects at the end of any command, and have them apply to the entire command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing special about it other than the fact that the whole redirection thing is a wholly brilliant concept.

The `<&3` simply tells `read` to take it's input from file handle 3 and the `3<file.txt` simply sets up file handle 3 for the relevant command set, which is the entire `while` loop.

You can read up on it in the `bash` man page under `REDIRECTION`.

You could also use the file desriptor form of `read -u 3` which I prefer since it allows me to get at *both* standard input and the extra file handle within the loop.

And, if you're thinking that somehow, file handle 3 is used before being set up, that's not so. The `3<file.txt` applies to the entire `while..done` loop, think of it like this:

```
(
    while read line <&3; do
        echo $line
    done
) 3<file.txt
```

In that sense, it's no different to:

```
sed 's/^/xx:/' <file.txt
```

in that the redirection is done *for* the command, not *following* it.

Comment: Doesn't the file handle typically have to be set up before it's used though? I think what's confusing me is that the file descriptor is being used anonymously before the file is specified.  
I'm unfamiliar if there is something to how Bash while loops are parsed that allows this use.

Comment: @user01189998819991197253, yes, it _is_ set up beforehand, it applies to the whole `while..done` structure. It's no different to `cat <xyzzy` - you don't say the redirection happens _after_ the `cat` in that case. I'll update for clarity.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now. I guess I couldn't find a suitable explanation when I was searching because I was looking for a file descriptor construct when the answer is really a shell command construct.